# LINQ functions for checking if a string exists before entering it into query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've currently got a query (psuedo code here!), such as:

```
var query = p.Companies.Any((a => a.Name != "" || a.Name.Contains(variable1) &&
                            (a => a.Description != "" || a.Description.Contains(variable2));
```

Now, obviously this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do as there's many more fields for me to check, but the base of my answer is - can I create a function/expression that is built up in such a way that it only generates the SQL it needs to?

Such as:

```
Expression<Func<Company, bool>> companyQuery;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(variable1)) {
   // build up my expression
}

// Pass expression through to query when finalized
```

Any ideas out there on this? Thanks!

Comment: You should use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) rather than != "". Do you have the same validation for each property?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using String.IsNullOrEmpty in my live code, I'm just writing sloppy pseudo code to illustrate purpose :) And yup, the same for each, so the generated SQL is pretty messy from what it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need to.  You can trust the database to optimize the query for you before executing it, so it's unlikely to be a problem.

That said, yes, you can do it, and it's not all that hard either.  (If the expressions were combined with OR semantics it would be a bit more work though.

```
IQueryable<Company> query = p.Companies.AsQueryable();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable1))
    query = query.Where(company => company.Name != "" || company.Name.Contains(variable1));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2))
    query = query.Where(company => company.Description != "" || company.Description .Contains(variable1));

bool result = query.Any();
```

This is a pattern I find being used a lot on advanced search screens.  If they're searching on this field, filter on this field, if they're not filtering on this field, don't include it.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your query on-demand with the `IQueryable` class, for example:

```
IQueryable<Company> query = p.Companies;

if (condition1)
{
    query = query.Where(expression1);
}

if (condition2)
{
    query = query.Where(expression2);
}
```